# xcode printf 0x0000000000000000 ,what does it means? it means null?

Tags: ios, xcode

I just printf self.view.window in the ViewController. then i get 0x0000000000000000? is it a address or something[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ok0ik.png)?

Comment: Yes. It means nil

Comment: You have to  check where you call this function

Answer (score 0):

Yep.
In the Objecitve-C, all of the Object variable is a pointer. And it is pointing to the Object's momery address. Such as 0x123abc...

The `nil` value is a special pointer and it point to 0x00000000. And the 0x00000000 means there is nothing.

---

看了题主应该貌似懂中文, 现在在使用 Xcode 做 Debug 的时候, 确实可能会显示 0x00, 实际上就是 nil 值. 0x00 的内存位置就是表示空, 表示没有任何对象, 也就是我们学习时候所理解的 "nil".